# How to fix a conversion failed error for date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting the following error for my query and not sure what is the reason:

> conversion failed when converting date and time from character sting

Here is the line getting the error in SQL Server 2012:

```
(CONVERT(DATE, (CONVERT(varchar, A.[Month-Bcast]) + ' 1 ' + CONVERT(varchar, A.[Year-bcast])))) AS [Last Update]
```

[Month-Bcast] = varchar(20), null
[Year-bcast] = varchar(20), null

Comment: We need to know the value that's failing the conversion. Have you considering using `TRY_CONVERT` instead?

Comment: what value are we talking about?

and are you saying replace all the convert to try_convert in the line above?

Comment: The value that you're trying to convert to a `date`. We can't access your server, nor can we see what you see; we only know you're getting an error but we don't know the value that is causing that error (as you haven't shared it). IF you can show us the value(s) that are causing the conversion error we can help you debug why.#

Comment: so the value is [Year-bcast] = varchar(20), null), and is simply "2018", "2017", "2016" ect

[Month-Bcast] = varchar(20, null)  values are "Jan", "feb", "Mar", "Apr" ect

Comment: None of those values generate an error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab4c562703460852a14228c9de317573). If it is one of those values, it's because one of those columns has an invalid value, like `'Jsn'` instead of `'Jan'`.

Comment: By the way, you should get in the habit of declaring lengths for your data types. `varchar` works here, as it defaults to a `varchar(30)` but one day you may well encounter a time when you get unexpected behaviour due to an undeclared length, scale, or precision.

Comment: Hey Lernu  the try_convert worked ! i found out the error was that the field had "jan  2019" in the [month b-cast] which was causing the error!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not reproducible.

The following test:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(DATE, (CONVERT(varchar, 'Oct') + ' 1 ' + CONVERT(varchar, '2017'))))
```

Produces no error, and results in:

```
2017-10-01
```

The error must be either in another part of the code, or due to some data in your table that is outside of what you described (valid Month/Year)

Comment: do you think it could be possible due to too much data?  i did a few tests..

first i tried to use that query somewhere else and like your test it worked somewhere else but wouldnt work with this query

second i tried removing this convert line above and this query worked telling me there is some issue with this line of code.. i tried testing it with "TRY_CONVERT (date(" so lets see if that works

Comment: No I don't think it could be too much data.   More likely it's a specific piece of data.

Comment: so looks like the (try_CONVERT(DATE, (CONVERT(varchar, A.[Month-Bcast]) + ' 1 ' + CONVERT(varchar, A.[Year-bcast])))) AS [Last Update]

worked on the top1000 rows and pulled the data so let me if the full query works.